# Page not found error while clicking on visit my profile link from email while logged into a different account

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-accounts

I recently signed up an account for my brother with android.stackexchange.com in Firefox browser. After registering with the new email(ka****@tang***.com), I received the registration mail with a link. I opened the registration email received to that email(ka****@tang***.com) in chrome browser and I clicked the link in the mail where I already have signed in with my user account. So I got a "page not found" error while clicking on visit my profile link. Here is the link received in the mail -

```
http://android.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/112351?welcome=1&a=6277e8&b=d943c5cd1b972070f2c52fe819ab4a2ad0b1c29ad285126731ec88996ceff95b&c=5
```

I emailed SO support team about the problem and they said to ask this on meta. They said there was a mismatch in the email(me and my brother's) that displayed this message.

> The reason you are getting a Not Found is that the user ID in the URL
>   does not match the user ID for your account on the site.

Suggestion:

Why not log out the user previously logged-in and show the profile page of the new user instead? OR Take him directly to the new user page while maintaining the login session of both users like Google does? So that we can switch user accounts at the top without having to login/logout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch. My suggestion is simply change the URL in the email to this:

```
http://[site here]/users/preferences/current?welcome=1
```

(e.g. https://android.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current?welcome=1)

And this will always show the Preferences tab of the currently logged in user.